# How to find R code invoked from ASP.NET C# ran successfully

Tags: c#, asp.net, r

I have a asp.net c# application in which I am invoking a R function. The R function does some calculations and inserts few values in multiple SQL tables and finally it updates a single value (from 0 to 1) in one of my SQL table to denote it had run successfully. I want to show a message to the user when the value got updated from 0 to 1 in the final table. Since there will be more rows (more than 10000), R takes time to update my final value from 0 to 1. Since I am not able to get the handshake from R Code and C#, I am not able to show the message exactly when the update from 0 to 1 happens.

- How to wait till my value is updated to 1?
- Can it be done in R code or in C# code?

Comment: How do you invoke the R function? Are you using R.net or are you launching a CMD from your app? Or something else?

Comment: I use RScriptRunner to invoke my r function